# Maps using a binary search tree to store data

Tags: java, dictionary, binary-search-tree

I need to implement a map interface, and store the data using a binary search tree. I have the interface implemented but I have no idea what I need to do next. So I guess my question is give me a crash course in binary search trees in Java. I understand trees in theory from discrete math courses, but I'm having trouble translating that over to programming.

This is the interface

```
public interface MapInterface<K,V> {

  public MapInterface<K,V> put(K key, V value);

  public V get(K key);

  public boolean containsKey(K key);

  public int size();

  public void visitAll(VisitorInterface<K,V> visitor);

  public void clear();

  public void remove(K key);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to google it ?

Comment: Best answer.... Google it.

Comment: I am currently, I always think it helps more to have specific help though.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste default java TreeMap implementation and simplify it via removing methods for balancing tree ;)